# Masking a name based length in C#

Tags: c#, regex

How do I make *masking* in the first name, middle name, and last name? Make masking based on the number of letters in each word in the name. Under the condition :

- If there are `3-4` letters then the last two letters will be masked.
- If there are *more* than `4` letters, the *first* `2` letters and the *last* `1` letter not be masked.

**Examples:**

1. `"Jo Dyne Roger" --> "Jo Dy** Ro**r"`
2. `"Samantha Summer" --> "Sa*****a Su***r"`

In **javascript** I'm using this code :

```
var name ="Jo Dyne Roger";
var regex1 =/\b(\w{1,2})(\w{2,}?)(\w?)\b/g;
var regex2 =/\b(\w{3})(\w+)(\w)\b/g;

console.log(name.replace(
    regex1,
    (_, first, middle, last) => `${first}${'*'.repeat(middle.length)}${last}`).replace(
    regex2,
    (_, first, middle, last) => `${first}${'*'.repeat(middle.length)}${last}`));
```

I don't understand how to implement the same in **C#**

Comment: The same regex approach can be made to work, you can name your capturing groups with `(?<first>...)` etc. Take a look at "c# named capturing groups" google. String has a constructor that takes a char and a number of repetitions.

Comment: @Fajar FWIW I'm not sure I'd use s regex approach in c#; it would probably be simpler and more readable to create a method that stars out the middle N characters of any string longer than N + 2(with a special case for length 4) chars then split the name on space and pass the fragments to the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's implement step by step, starting from masking single name:

> if there are 3-4 letters then the last two letters will be masked. If there are more 4 letters, the first 2 letters and the last 1 letter not be masked

```
private static string MyMask(string value) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.Length < 3)
    return value;
  else if (value.Length <= 4)
    return value.Substring(0, 2) + 
           new string('*', value.Length - 2);
  else
    return value.Substring(0, 2) + 
           new string('*', value.Length - 3) + 
           value.Substring(value.Length - 1);
}
```

Having mask we can write an easy regular expression: all we want is to `Replace` words with `3` letters or more into corresponding `MyMask`

```
 string source = "Jo Dyne Roger";

 string result = Regex.Replace(source, @"\b\w{3,}\b", match => MyMask(match.Value));
```

**Demo:**

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "Jo Dyne Roger",
    "Samantha Summer",
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test} --> {Regex.Replace(test, @"\b\w{3,}\b", match => MyMask(match.Value))}")
  );

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
Jo Dyne Roger --> Jo Dy** Ro**r
Samantha Summer --> Sa*****a Su***r
```

Comment: (With a footnote to ensure not to call this on strings of 0 or 1 length - the regex will prevent this but it may not always be used with a regex. Perhaps an `>1` extension to the if?)